# read xml and write it inside resource.resx

Tags: c#, xml, globalization

Am try to bind xml to resource.resx inorder to complete globilazation

this is my code,

```
            System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("..//Swedish.xml");

            ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter("..//App_GlobalResources/Resource.sv-SE.resx");

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "string")
                    writer.AddResource(reader.GetAttribute("name"), reader.ReadString());
            }

            writer.Generate();
            writer.Close();
```

And my xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <resources>
 <string name="Account"> konto </string>
 <string name="AccountDetails">Kontouppgifter</string>
 <string name="CompanyManagement">Företagsledning</string>
 <string name="Logout">Logga ut</string>
  </resources>
```

Now my problem is Am getting xml only if i set the whole path
Can Guys help me

i also try by,

```
     System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("~/Swedish.xml");
     System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"/Swedish.xml");
```

Comment: am completely a begineer on this

Comment: Is the application you try to translate the application that runs the code you showed?

Comment: @Mathias yes,and the code above is to bind xml to resource file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is some what cleared when I changed code,

```
 string xmlPath = Server.MapPath("~/XMLFile1.xml");
 string resourcePath = Server.MapPath("~/LocalResource/Resource.sv-SE.resx");
 System.Xml.XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlPath);
 ResXResourceWriter writer = new ResXResourceWriter(resourcePath);
```

but Some time run-time error is happenning